# Can I use the method of seperation variables to solve the following ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can I use the method of seperation variables to solve the following ODE
$$F'(x)=\frac{a}{(F(x))^2}+c$$
where $a,c>0$

If without $c>0$, I can solve it , but now how can I solve this equation?

Comment: Yes, "switch" sides: $\frac{dF}{dx} = \frac{a + cF^2}{F^2}$ which would lead to: $\frac{F^2}{a + cF^2}dF = dx$, then integrate both sides.

Comment: could you give me the detailed form of $\int\frac{F^2}{a+cF^2}dF$, I have no idea about  $\int\frac{F^2}{a+cF^2}dF= \int\frac{1}{\frac{a}{F^2}+c}dF$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x = \int \frac{F^2}{a+cF^2} dF = \frac 1a \int \frac{F^2}{1+\frac caF^2} dF.$$

Susbstitute $u=\sqrt{\frac c a}F$

$$x= \sqrt{\frac a {c^3}} \int \frac{u^2}{1+u^2} du$$

$$x= \sqrt{\frac a {c^3}}( \int du -\int \frac{1}{1+u^2} du)$$

$$x= \sqrt{\frac a {c^3}}( u -\arctan (u))+C$$

$$x= \frac F c - \sqrt{\frac a {c^3}}\arctan (F\sqrt{\frac  c a})+C$$

Answer (score 3):

Rearrange to get $$\frac{F^2}{a+cF^2} dF = dx$$ which is a separable equation. Integrate both sides to get $$x = \int \frac{F^2}{a+cF^2} dF = \frac 1a \int \frac{F^2}{1+\frac caF^2} dF.$$ Let $\tan u = \sqrt{\frac ca} F$, then $\sec^2u \,du = \sqrt{\frac{c}{a}} \, dF$ so we get $$x = \frac 1a \int \frac{\frac ac \tan^2u}{1+\tan^2u} \sqrt{\frac ac}\sec^2 u \, du = \frac 1c \sqrt{\frac ac}\int \frac{\tan^2u}{\sec^2 u} \sec^2 u \, du = \frac 1c \sqrt{\frac ac}\int \tan^2u \, du$$ and thus $$x = \frac 1c \sqrt{\frac ac} \left ( \tan u - u\right)+K = \frac 1c \sqrt{\frac ac} \left ( \sqrt{\frac ca}F - \tan^{-1} \left( \sqrt{\frac ca}F\right) \right) +K$$ Therefore the solution is given implicitly by 
$$x = \frac 1c F - \sqrt{\frac{a}{c^3}}\tan^{-1} \left( \sqrt{\frac ca}F\right)+K$$ where $K$ is our integration constant.

Comment: I've never liked the notation $\tan^{-1}$. I get it, it's part of the notation for an inverse function: $f^{-1}(x)$. But to me, it confuses the difference between $\tan^2(x) = (\tan(x))^2$ and $\cot(x) = (\tan(x))^{-1}$ vs. $\tan^{-1}(x) = \arctan(x) \neq (\tan(x))^{-1} = \cot(x)$).

Comment: I disagree. It is very common to see the $^{-1}$ symbol to denote a functional inverse rather than a multiplicative inverse. This is why we call $1/\tan(x)$ a new function, namely $\cot(x)$. I personally like to use the $\tan^{-1}(x)$ as it is more compact than writing out $\arctan(x)$ or $\text{atan}(x)$, and every letter contributes when working out long calculations. To each their own!